# SQL WHERE with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. One is Department and the other is Employe. I want to find the departments where all the employees have a certain salary. How can I do that?

```
select Departement.Nom_Departement, Employe.nom, Employe.Salaire
from Departement join Employe
on Employe.Code_Departement = Departement.Code_Departement
where **all** Employe.Salaire > 50000
```

I want something like the above.

Comment: have you tried moving that `Employe.Salarie` to the `on` clause? something like `on ... and Employe.Salaire >50000`.

Comment: Do you want departments where **all** of the employees have salaries > 50000 and exclude departments where **any** employee has a salary <= 50000 (or perhaps no employees)? If so, you can `GROUP BY Departement.Nom_Departement`, calculate `MIN(Employe.Salaire)` for each group, and use a `HAVING` clause to filter for `MIN(Employe.Salaire) > 50000`.  See the article [SELECT - HAVING (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql) for syntax and examples.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: You need to get creative and think of this backwards. Another way to look at it is "A. Get me all departments but then B. Remove any departments where at least one employee has income below 50000". Firstly, can you write sql to "list all departments where at least one employee has income below 50000"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list employees which all employees of that department has salary > 50000, you can use `having` to get department than select all employees in that department. Here is the sample

```
SELECT d.Name_Department, e.Name AS Employee_Name, e.Salary AS Employee_Salary
FROM Department d
JOIN Employee e ON e.Code_Department = d.Code_Department
WHERE d.Code_Department IN (
    SELECT Code_Department
    FROM Employee
    GROUP BY Code_Department
    HAVING MIN(Salary) > 50000
)
```

You can check on [my fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/MOwIDM50)